the folder /data/user/0 encrypted after ran 'adb shell locksettings clear'
I am seeking assistance with an issue I encountered today while working with my Android device, a Redmi 9 running OS 10.
After connecting the device via ADB, I set a password using the appropriate command. A few minutes later, I attempted to remove it by executing adb shell locksettings clear. Since then, the /data/user/0 directory appears to have become encrypted.
I have attempted to verify the password and restore it, followed by running the verification process again, but unfortunately, these steps did not resolve the issue.
I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this problem.
logcat logs:
09-25 18:14:19.936   549   549 D lights  : write_int open fd=7
 09-25 18:14:19.937   716   839 D AAL     : 09-25 06:14:19.871 BL= 233,ESS= 256, 09-25 06:14:19.887 BL= 190,ESS= 256, 09-25 06:14:19.904 BL= 147,ESS= 256, 09-25 06:14:19.920 BL= 105,ESS= 256, 09-25 06:14:19.937 BL=  62,ESS= 256,
 09-25 18:14:19.952   716   839 D AAL     : onBacklightChanged: 53/1023 -> 20/1023(phy:20/4095)
 09-25 18:14:19.969   716   839 D AAL     : 09-25 06:14:19.953 BL=  20,ESS= 256,
 09-25 18:14:20.030  3016  3016 D ICU     : Time zone APEX file found: /apex/com.android.tzdata/etc/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
 09-25 18:14:20.050  3016  3016 I app_process: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
 09-25 18:14:20.087  3016  3016 W app_process: JNI RegisterNativeMethods: attempt to register 0 native methods for android.media.AudioAttributes
 09-25 18:14:20.097  3016  3016 D AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.locksettings.LockSettingsCmd
 09-25 18:14:20.216   544   544 I microgatekeeper: ~~ Enter ree verify ~~
 09-25 18:14:20.216   544   544 I microgatekeeper: ~~ ut_gk_transfer_buff begin ~~
 09-25 18:14:20.227   544   544 I microgatekeeper: ~~ ut_gk_transfer_buff end ~~
 09-25 18:14:20.228   544   544 I microgatekeeper: ~~ From ree verify, success ~~
 09-25 18:14:20.231   690   690 I SELinux : avc:  received policyload notice (seqno=2)
 09-25 18:14:20.239   690   690 D keystore: AddAuthenticationToken: timestamp = 4419558, time_received = 2625
 09-25 18:14:20.254   453   453 I beanpodkeymaster: Enter BeanpodKeymaster BeginOperation
 09-25 18:14:20.256   453   453 E beanpodkeymaster: Received 24 byte response
 09-25 18:14:20.256   453   453 I beanpodkeymaster: Exit BeanpodKeymaster BeginOperation
 09-25 18:14:20.259   453   453 I beanpodkeymaster: Enter BeanpodKeymaster UpdateOperation
 09-25 18:14:20.260   453   453 E beanpodkeymaster: Received 180 byte response
 09-25 18:14:20.260   453   453 I beanpodkeymaster: Exit BeanpodKeymaster UpdateOperation
 09-25 18:14:20.263   453   453 I beanpodkeymaster: Enter BeanpodKeymaster FinishOperation
 09-25 18:14:20.264   453   453 E beanpodkeymaster: Received 20 byte response
 09-25 18:14:20.264   453   453 I beanpodkeymaster: Exit BeanpodKeymaster FinishOperation
 09-25 18:14:20.270   544   544 I microgatekeeper: ~~ Enter ree verify ~~
 09-25 18:14:20.270   544   544 I microgatekeeper: ~~ ut_gk_transfer_buff begin ~~
 09-25 18:14:20.282   544   544 I microgatekeeper: ~~ ut_gk_transfer_buff end ~~
 09-25 18:14:20.282   544   544 I microgatekeeper: ~~ From ree verify, success ~~
 09-25 18:14:20.283   690   690 D keystore: AddAuthenticationToken: timestamp = 4419612, time_received = 2625
 09-25 18:14:20.286   544   544 I microgatekeeper: ~~ Enter ree verify ~~
 09-25 18:14:20.286   544   544 I microgatekeeper: ~~ ut_gk_transfer_buff begin ~~
 09-25 18:14:20.298   544   544 I microgatekeeper: ~~ ut_gk_transfer_buff end ~~
 09-25 18:14:20.298   544   544 I microgatekeeper: ~~ From ree verify, success ~~
 09-25 18:14:20.299   690   690 D keystore: AddAuthenticationToken: timestamp = 4419628, time_received = 2625
 09-25 18:14:20.303   690   690 I keystore: calling unlock when already unlocked, ignoring.
 --------- beginning of system
 09-25 18:14:20.304  1242  1255 I LockSettingsService: Unlocking user 0 with secret only, length 32
 09-25 18:14:20.311   390   390 W vold    : Password present but stretching is nopassword
 09-25 18:14:20.311   390   390 E vold    : Openssl error: 0
 09-25 18:14:20.312   390   390 E vold    : Failed to find working ce key for user 0
 09-25 18:14:20.312   390   390 E vold    : Couldn't read key for 0
 09-25 18:14:20.315  1242  1255 E StorageManagerService:
 09-25 18:14:20.315  1242  1255 E StorageManagerService: android.os.ServiceSpecificException:  (code 0)
 09-25 18:14:20.315  1242  1255 E StorageManagerService:         at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2089)
 09-25 18:14:20.315  1242  1255 E StorageManagerService:         at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2043)
 09-25 18:14:20.315  1242  1255 E StorageManagerService:         at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1991)
 09-25 18:14:20.315  1242  1255 E StorageManagerService:         at android.os.IVold$Stub$Proxy.unlockUserKey(IVold.java:2488)
 09-25 18:14:20.315  1242  1255 E StorageManagerService:         at com.android.server.StorageManagerService.unlockUserKey(StorageManagerService.java:2841)
 09-25 18:14:20.315  1242  1255 E StorageManagerService:         at com.android.server.am.UserController.unlockUserCleared(UserController.java:1313)
 09-25 18:14:20.315  1242  1255 E StorageManagerService:         at com.android.server.am.UserController.unlockUser(UserController.java:1280)
 09-25 18:14:20.315  1242  1255 E StorageManagerService:         at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.unlockUser(ActivityManagerService.java:18185)
 09-25 18:14:20.315  1242  1255 E StorageManagerService:         at com.android.server.locksettings.LockSettingsService.unlockUser(LockSettingsService.java:1232)
 09-25 18:14:20.315  1242  1255 E StorageManagerService:         at com.android.server.locksettings.LockSettingsService.spBasedDoVerifyCredential(LockSettingsService.java:2612)
 09-25 18:14:20.315  1242  1255 E StorageManagerService:         at com.android.server.locksettings.LockSettingsService.doVerifyCredential(LockSettingsService.java:1823)
 09-25 18:14:20.315  1242  1255 E StorageManagerService:         at com.android.server.locksettings.LockSettingsService.checkCredential(LockSettingsService.java:1796)
 09-25 18:14:20.315  1242  1255 E StorageManagerService:         at com.android.internal.widget.LockPatternUtils.checkCredential(LockPatternUtils.java:392)
 09-25 18:14:20.315  1242  1255 E StorageManagerService:         at com.android.internal.widget.LockPatternUtils.checkPassword(LockPatternUtils.java:546)
 09-25 18:14:20.315  1242  1255 E StorageManagerService:         at com.android.internal.widget.LockPatternUtils.checkPassword(LockPatternUtils.java:516)
 09-25 18:14:20.315  1242  1255 E StorageManagerService:         at com.android.server.locksettings.LockSettingsShellCommand.checkCredential(LockSettingsShellCommand.java:244)
 09-25 18:14:20.315  1242  1255 E StorageManagerService:         at com.android.server.locksettings.LockSettingsShellCommand.onCommand(LockSettingsShellCommand.java:74)
 09-25 18:14:20.315  1242  1255 E StorageManagerService:         at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:111)
 09-25 18:14:20.315  1242  1255 E StorageManagerService:         at com.android.server.locksettings.LockSettingsService.onShellCommand(LockSettingsService.java:2193)
 09-25 18:14:20.315  1242  1255 E StorageManagerService:         at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:881)
 09-25 18:14:20.315  1242  1255 E StorageManagerService:         at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:765)
 09-25 18:14:20.315  1242  1255 E StorageManagerService:         at com.android.internal.widget.ILockSettings$Stub.onTransact(ILockSettings.java:956)
 09-25 18:14:20.315  1242  1255 E StorageManagerService:         at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1021)
 09-25 18:14:20.315  1242  1255 E StorageManagerService:         at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:994)
 09-25 18:14:20.317  1242  1255 D LockSettingsService: unlockUser finished
 09-25 18:14:20.319  1242  1255 I LockSettingsService: Disabling escrow token on user 0
 09-25 18:14:20.322  1242  1255 I LockSettingsService: Caching SP for user 0
 09-25 18:14:20.322  1242  1267 I DropBoxManagerService: add tag=system_server_wtf isTagEnabled=true flags=0x2
 09-25 18:14:20.324  1242  1242 I LockSettingsService: Removing SP from cache for user 0
 09-25 18:14:20.328  1242  1267 W AES     : Exception Log handling...
 09-25 18:14:20.331  1242  1267 D AES     : ExceptionLog: notify aed, process:system_server pid:1242 cause:system_server_wtf
 09-25 18:14:20.331  1242  1267 W AES     : skip for Exp level 0
 09-25 18:14:20.333  3016  3016 W BpBinder: Slow Binder: BpBinder transact took 230 ms, interface=com.android.internal.widget.ILockSettings, code=1598246212 oneway=false
 09-25 18:14:20.334  3016  3016 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
 09-25 18:14:20.335  1424  2678 D KeyguardViewMediator: setKeyguardEnabled(true)
 09-25 18:14:20.337  1424  1424 V KeyguardUpdateMonitor: startListeningForFingerprint()
 09-25 18:14:20.348  1242  2367 D KeySyncTask: Key sync not needed.
 09-25 18:14:20.424  3016  3016 D RefBase : RefBase: Explicit destruction, weak count = 0 (in 0xf146f0d8)
 09-25 18:14:20.424  3016  3016 W RefBase : CallStack::getCurrentInternal not linked, returning null
 09-25 18:14:20.424  3016  3016 W RefBase : CallStack::logStackInternal not linked
 09-25 18:14:20.443   667  3017 I ADB_SERVICES: post waitpid (pid=3016) status=0000
 09-25 18:14:20.444   667   667 I ADB_SERVICES: for fd 24, revents = 2011


Does this answer your question? How exactly does FBE's key derivation work?
